# What is the distribution of a uniform with a bound drawn from a uniform?

Tags: uniform-distribution, compound-distributions

Suppose I have a uniform distribution $X \sim U[a,1]$ with $a \sim U[c,1]$? How can I characterize the CDF of X?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Michael.  What steps have you taken to reformulate or start answering this question?  For instance, have you tried to apply the definition of a CDF?  What were the obstacles to deriving a satisfactory answer?

Comment: From the definition, I was able to derive a PDF but not a CDF. I will post the PDF later today in a suggested answer.

Comment: @MichaelLachanski: Did you have any progress? Then you can answer your own question!